# Intent - go to another activity dynamically

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I would like to use in my app dynamically change to another activity

```
//this code works:
Intent intent = new Intent (Setup.this, SupportedApps.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I want to use it dynamically it gives me error: "Cannot resolve Constructor"

```
//this code DOESN'T works:
String[] classArrayList = {"SupportedApps.class"}
Intent intent = new Intent (Setup.this, classArrayList [0]}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why do you keep SupportedApps.class in string array?

Comment: How they should be stored? I have few class and I defined them in String array

Comment: `Class[] classArrayList = {SupportedApps.class};`.

Comment: I made new array Class[] classArrayList = {SupportedApps.class}; and the code is now  Intent i = new Intent(); i.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), classArrayList[0] );But still cannot resolve method 'setclassName

Comment: All you had to change in the posted code is what I gave above (apart from the typos).

Comment: Could you please write full code in Answer section (I'm too tired and can't thing straight)

Comment: There's no need for `setClassName()` with the `Class` array: `Class[] classArrayList = {SupportedApps.class};`, `Intent intent = new Intent(Setup.this, classArrayList[0]);`, `startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: String's aren't Class objects. You can't use a string there, try using a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this way**

```
Class[] classArrayList = {SupportedApps.class};
Intent intent = new Intent(this, classArrayList[0]);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you, It seems to work fine. I have to test it at home, I tried the same code yesterday at my home PC and I got error, but now at work it works. I had to do "Build - Clean Project" and "Build - Rebuild Project".

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: This is working for me, at my home PC I had to do "Build - Clean Project" and "Build - Rebuild Project".

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below example. it's working perfect for me.

```
 final Class[] classArrayList = {SecondActivity.class};
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, classArrayList[0]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question is how to start activity, which name is represented as `String`. There is `Class.forName(String)` method which returns `Class` object associated with given String.

```
    String[] classes = {"com.packagename.SupportedApps"};
    Class clazz = Class.forName(classes[0]);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace `String[]` with `Class[]`